# External SVG file in clippath

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have SVG file that i created it in photoshop. I would like to use it in my html page with clip-path property. I am trying to implement it as using clip-path:url(#mysvg); and paste the svg code to my html page. But i does not work. How can i do that?

**My purpose is like this with css:**

[image]

Here is the .svg file:
https://svgshare.com/i/dfw.svg

Here is the svg code

```html
<!--IMAGE-->
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 814 506" >
    <image id="image" class="image__svg-image" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#mask)" x="-100px" xlink:href="https://res.cloudinary.com/alvarosaburido/image/upload/v1589435086/blog/The%20Magic%20of%20SVG%20Clip-path/pic_yo5eyq.png" />
</svg>


<!--MY SVG FILE-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1920" viewBox="0 0 1920 1920">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c142 79.160924, 2017/07/13-01:06:39        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                              
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #fff;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="rect1" class="cls-1" d="M133,333.637L1426.05,171.265a157.557,157.557,0,0,1,175.99,136.647l157.93,1256.5L466.929,1726.79a157.574,157.574,0,0,1-176-136.65Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There's no element with id="mask" in your SVG file. You need there to be a clipPath element with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the viewBox of the `<svg>` is 100 in width and the image also takes up 100% of the width. So, no matter the actual width of the image it will always fill the entire SVG.

The `<clipPath>` fits in the size of the viewBox of the `<svg>` that holds the image. I know the width is 100, so I made the clippath 70 in height and width plus the extra height that the rotation takes up. This matches kind of the height of the images (unknown at this point).

I replaced the content of the `<clipPath>`. It is more "transparent" what the clip path does and easier to manipulate.

```html
<!--IMAGE-->
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300">
    <image width="100%" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/alvarosaburido/image/upload/v1589435086/blog/The%20Magic%20of%20SVG%20Clip-path/pic_yo5eyq.png" clip-path="url(#mask)" />
</svg>


<!--MY SVG FILE-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask" transform="translate(15 0) rotate(-10 60 0)">
      <rect width="50" height="50" />
      <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" />
      <rect x="20" width="50" height="50" rx="10" />
      <rect y="20" width="50" height="50" rx="10" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Update

OP asks if the original path can be used as a clip-path. It can, but the viewBox needs to be modified accordingly. So, if the viewbox `0 0 2300 1800` is used the path fits the image.

```html
<!--IMAGE-->
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2300 1800" width="300">
    <image width="100%" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/alvarosaburido/image/upload/v1589435086/blog/The%20Magic%20of%20SVG%20Clip-path/pic_yo5eyq.png" clip-path="url(#mask)" />
</svg>


<!--MY SVG FILE-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask" transform="translate(350 0)">
      <path id="rect1" class="cls-1" d="M133,333.637L1426.05,171.265a157.557,157.557,0,0,1,175.99,136.647l157.93,1256.5L466.929,1726.79a157.574,157.574,0,0,1-176-136.65Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Update

To "path" or not to "path", that is the question. This third example is a better solution. The path is simpler and there are not that many child elements in `<clipPath>`.

```html
<!--IMAGE-->
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11 11" width="300">
    <image width="100%" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/alvarosaburido/image/upload/v1589435086/blog/The%20Magic%20of%20SVG%20Clip-path/pic_yo5eyq.png" clip-path="url(#mask)" />
</svg>


<!--MY SVG FILE-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask" transform="translate(2 0) rotate(-10 7 0)">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 6 0 A 1 1 90 0 1 7 1 L 7 7 L 1 7 A 1 1 90 0 1 0 6 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Update

This fourth example is using the original path, BUT defined in a `<clipPath>` and used as an external reference in CSS. The external SVG file have the following content:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="mask" transform="translate(350 0)">
      <path id="rect1" class="cls-1" d="M133,333.637L1426.05,171.265a157.557,157.557,0,0,1,175.99,136.647l157.93,1256.5L466.929,1726.79a157.574,157.574,0,0,1-176-136.65Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

But for this example I replace the URL (like `https://svgshare.com/i/dfw.svg#rect`) to the SVG file with a data URI.

```css
svg>image {
  clip-path: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxkZWZzPgogICAgPGNsaXBQYXRoIGlkPSJtYXNrIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgzNTAgMCkiPgogICAgICA8cGF0aCBpZD0icmVjdDEiIGNsYXNzPSJjbHMtMSIgZD0iTTEzMywzMzMuNjM3TDE0MjYuMDUsMTcxLjI2NWExNTcuNTU3LDE1Ny41NTcsMCwwLDEsMTc1Ljk5LDEzNi42NDdsMTU3LjkzLDEyNTYuNUw0NjYuOTI5LDE3MjYuNzlhMTU3LjU3NCwxNTcuNTc0LDAsMCwxLTE3Ni0xMzYuNjVaIi8+CiAgICA8L2NsaXBQYXRoPgogIDwvZGVmcz4KPC9zdmc+#mask');
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2300 1800" width="300">
  <image width="100%" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/alvarosaburido/image/upload/v1589435086/blog/The%20Magic%20of%20SVG%20Clip-path/pic_yo5eyq.png" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It works well but my question is not compeletly such that. I wanted to learn how can i make clip-path with my svg draw. It was the easiest one. If I would have much more complicated design, how can i solve it?

Comment: @phzdjz I updated my answer with a second example where I use your path.

Comment: Still it is not my answer. How did you do that? I just would like to learn it to do my jobs next time on my own.

Comment: @phzdjz A fourth example has been added. Now I use an external SVG in CSS. But your SVG file needs to define a clipPath, it is not enough just defining af path.

Comment: Actually in this [link](https://ibb.co/gvxxC6h) example, photo is not fitting into svg file. In every photo, it is changing. How can i make it for all photos as in the same fitting?

Comment: And also there is one more example how to do that but i dont know how can i convert my svg file like such example [click to go example](https://cssfordesigners.com/articles/clip-path-scaling)